# How to use QGSFileWidget to save file?

Tags: qgis, python, save, qgis-custom-widgets

I am writing a QGis 2.18 plugin.
I am designing the plugin with QT, using QGis widgets.  I can use QgsFileWidget to open file, but I did not find how to use it to save file.
If I try to define an output filename from my plugin, I read an error saying the file could not be found, which I believe means that the widget is in 'read' mode not in 'save' mode.

How can I set, from my python code, the QgsFileWidget to operate in save mode, and therefore let me define a filename for saving my output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible in 2.18 - the file save mode was not added until 3.0

Answer (score 7):

I know the question is regarding QGIS 2.18, however for anyone viewing for QGIS 3.x, you can use:

```
QgsFileWidget.setStorageMode(QgsFileWidget.SaveFile)
```

(which is the equivalent of `QgsFileWidget.setStorageMode(3)` as `QgsFileWidget.SaveFile` returns 3)