# Where in QGIS Plugin code should I set the QgsFileWidget to GetDirectory?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt

I have a QgsFileWidget in my dialog that enables the choosing of a file. I need to set it to choose a folder instead. I understand that I need to use something like:

```
self.dlg.outputFilePathChooser.StorageMode.GetDirectory
```

To change this setting. However the above when placed in the run(self) function does not change the setting.
I used the Plugin Builder to generate a blueprint and all my code is under the run(self) function. I've tried placing this line of code (which doesn't give any errors in the Log) in various places e.g. after if result: in the run(self) function or in the initGui(self) function.

I have tried adding QgsFileWidget before GetDirectory like so:

```
self.dlg.outputFilePathChooser.QgsFileWidget.StorageMode.GetDirectory
```

But get the error 'AttributeError: 'QgsFileWidget' object has no attribute 'QgsFileWidget''

I have also tried formatting it like at the following link, this prevents the plugin from opening, with error 'NameError: name 'GetDirectory' is not defined':

[How to use QGSFileWidget to save file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278828/how-to-use-qgsfilewidget-to-save-file)

How do I format & where do I place the code to achieve my desired result (QgsFileWidget opens a dialog to pick a folder, NOT a file)?

Comment: And if you are using QTDesigner to create the layout select he QgsFileWidget and go to Property Editor > QgsFileWdget > storageMode to select the mode you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from qgis.gui import QgsFileWidget
    from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QFormLayout
    # your other imports ... 
    
    def picked_directory(self, path):
        print(self.folder_widget.filePath())    

   .........
    def your_function_xy (self):
        self.folder_widget = QgsFileWidget()
        self.folder_widget.setDialogTitle('Select Directory')
        self.folder_widget.setStorageMode(QgsFileWidget.StorageMode.GetDirectory)
        self.folder_widget.fileChanged.connect(self.picked_directory)
        layout = QFormLayout() # or something else
        layout.addWidget(self.folder_widget)
        self.dlg.setLayout(layout)
        self.dlg.show()   # self.dlg -> your dialog defined somewhere else
        ... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `storageMode` is not the correct method.

As per [QgsFileWidget](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsFileWidget.html#qgis.gui.QgsFileWidget) documentation:

- **storageMode**: Returns the widget's storage mode (i.e. file or
  directory)
- **setStorageMode**: Sets the widget's storage mode (i.e. file
  or directory)

So considering this and that your widget's name is `outputFilePathChooser`, you can change the storage mode with this line:

```
self.dlg.outputFilePathChooser.setStorageMode(QgsFileWidget.GetDirectory)
```

It can be inserted in the `run()` function in the `yourPluginName.py` file.

Also note that methods don't have uppercase. `setStorageMode` and **not** `SetStorageMode`.